# 3 divs in fixed size container: 2 have fixed size, 1 should stretch

Tags: html, css

Say I have a fixed size `div`, which contains 3 further `divs`:

- The first and the last one have a fixed size as well, the middle one should fill the rest of the space

```css
 #container {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
 }
 #a,
 #c {
   height: 20px;
 }
 #b {
   height: 60px; // this should be a generic value...
 }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="a">A</div>
  <div id="b">B</div>
  <div id="c">C</div>
</div>
```

How can I make the `#b` div to automatically stretch.

The three divs(`#a`, `#b`, `#c`) should fill the entire `height` of `#container`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Flexbox` and `flex-direction: column`, so if you set `flex: 1` on `#b` it will take rest of free space.

```css
#container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#a,#c {
  height: 20px;
  background: lightblue;
}
#b {
  flex: 1;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="a">A</div>
  <div id="b">B</div>
  <div id="c">C</div>
</div>
```

Update: I guess you could do same thing with css tables [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/555/)

Comment: This works, but support in IE is limited according to http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Answer (score 1):

use CSS3 `calc()`

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0
}
#container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
}
#a,
#c {
  height: 20px;
  background: red
}
#b {
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
  background: green
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="a">A</div>
  <div id="b">B</div>
  <div id="c">C</div>
</div>
```

If you want to support IE8, you can use `display:table`/`table-row`

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}
#container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: table
}
#container > div {
  display: table-row
}
#a,
#c {
  height: 20px;
  background: red
}
#b {
  background: green
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="a">A</div>
  <div id="b">B</div>
  <div id="c">C</div>
</div>
```

Comment: flexbox also works, but calc() has better support in recent versions of IE, according to http://caniuse.com/#search=calc vs http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Comment: I always try to give a wide support ;)

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox was made for this exact problem. it's magic!
Note: Include webkit for better support.

```css
html,body{height:100%}
#container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display:-webkit-flex;
  display:flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction:column;
  flex-direction:column;
}

#a, #c {
  height: 20px;
  background:#333;
}

#b {
  height: 100%; // this should be a generic value...
  background:#eee;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
   <div id="a">A</div>
   <div id="b">B</div>
   <div id="c">C</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What if make position absolute for `a` and `c`, and add padding to `container` equal to `a` and `c` height, and make `b` 100% height?

```css
#container {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   padding: 20px 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   position: relative;
 }
 #a,
 #c {
   height: 20px;
   width: 100%;
   border: solid 1px red;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
 }
 #b {
   height: 100%;
   border: solid 1px green;
 }
 
 #a {top: 0;}
 #c{bottom: 0;}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="a">A</div>
  <div id="b">B</div>
  <div id="c">C</div>
</div>
```